# "code ." is not working in the command line for Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I've been using Visual Studio Code to do some Python development in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS distro for a few years now. I got started doing this by following [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial). Starting this morning though, the `code .` command I use to open VS Code from my working directory with the WSL hasn't been opening VS Code. The first time, it appeared to be updating a VS Code remote server, and then never opened up the window. Further times I've prompted that command, it's just returned nothing.

I've tried opening and reclosing the WSL, and restarting my computer, but that hasn't changed anything. I checked my PATH variable but the path to the "code tunnel" appears to still be listed there.
[Screenshot of WSL terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Ea5.png)

As requested, here is the output of running `> Help: About` in VS Code's command palette.

```
Version: 1.82.0 (user setup)
Commit: 8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314
Date: 2023-09-06T22:07:07.438Z
Electron: 25.8.0
ElectronBuildId: 23503258
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
```

Something that I think is also worth noting: I have tried reinstalling the VS Code server by removing (`rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/`) and reinstalling it (`code .`), and I am getting an error in the WSL terminal:

```
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314)
Downloading: 100%
Unpacking: 100%
mv: cannot move '/home/axf190026/.vscode-server/bin/8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314-1694443375' to '/home/axf190026/.vscode-server/bin/8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314': Permission denied
Unpacked 1794 files and folders to /home/axf190026/.vscode-server/bin/8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314.
```

**Update as of 9/14/2023:**
I ran the command `code .` and it appeared to successfully update the VS Code Server, without the above mv error:

```
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (6509174151d557a81c9d0b5f8a5a1e9274db5585)
Downloading: 100%
Unpacking: 100%
Unpacked 1794 files and folders to /home/axf190026/.vscode-server/bin/6509174151d557a81c9d0b5f8a5a1e9274db5585.
```

However, this still doesn't open up VS Code in my current working directory. I ran `code . --verbose` to see if there were any problems there, but it all looks fine:

```
Invoking: cd "/mnt/c/Users/axf190026/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code" && ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "/mnt/c/Users/axf190026/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe" "resources/app/out/cli.js" "--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node" "--verbose" "--folder-uri=vscode-remote://wsl+Ubuntu-22.04/home/axf190026/Projects/TRAP/Security/TRAP_Propositional_Logic/TA+Interface-NAND2" "--remote=wsl+Ubuntu-22.04"
```

So I'm still at a loss of what to do here.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. What do you see when you run with logging (`--log <level>` see `code --help`)? You might also want to raise a crash report issue ticket (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Native-Crash-Issues). If you raise an issue ticket, please ping me with a link to it.

Comment: Sure! I have added the information above. I also found an error when attempting to remove and reinstall the VS Code Server on WSL perhaps this is helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 9/15/2023:

I tried running `code .` again, and it started to update the VS Code Server. It finished successfully, and upon finishing, a VS Code window opened up my current working Ubuntu directory. I'll take this to mean that a developer at Microsoft has solved the issue behind the scenes.

Here's what ran in my Ubuntu terminal following the `code .` command:

```
Updating VS Code Server to version abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d)
Downloading: 100%
Unpacking: 100%
Unpacked 1794 files and folders to /home/axf190026/.vscode-server/bin/abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d.
```

And here's my Visual Studio Code `> Help: About` output.

```
Version: 1.82.2 (user setup)
Commit: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Date: 2023-09-14T05:55:25.390Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
```